# MS SQL 13.0: разные результаты выполнения ХП с одинаковыми параметрами

Tags: sql-server

Добрый день.

Сегодня я столкнулся вот с чем:

Если **выполнить хранимую** процедуру (exec procedure param1, param2) и взять **ее текст** и просто **выполнить его**, то результат будет **разным**.
Я честно не пойму в чем дело.

**Прошу указать на мои ошибки (вряд-ли это глюк SM SQL, мне так кажется)**

Вот что я делаю:

1. Запуск хранимки:

   ```
   exec [dbo].[proc_GetClientsSum] @dateFrom, @dateTo
   ```
2. Текст **этой же хранимки**, только в виде обычного скрипта:

   ```
   DECLARE @dateFrom datetime = '2016.09.01 00:00:00'
   DECLARE @dateTo datetime = '2016.09.30 23:59:59'       

   DECLARE @DELIVERED int = 9;
   DECLARE @SENT int = 2;
   DECLARE @GSM_PROVIDER int = 5;

   DECLARE @gmsMessages table
   (
     messageId int,
     recipient varchar(20),
     [count] int
   )

   ;WITH CTE AS
   (
     SELECT
       m.messageId,
       m.recipient,
       ms.providerId,
       ms.statusValue.value('(//Count/text())[1]', 'int') [count],
       ms.statusId,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ms.messageId ORDER BY ms.messageStatusId DESC) rowNumber
     FROM [dbo].[Messages] m (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[MessageStatus] (NOLOCK) ms 
       ON m.messageId = ms.messageId
     WHERE m.[dt] >= @dateFrom AND  m.[dt] < @dateTo
       AND statusId = @SENT
   )


   INSERT INTO @gmsMessages(messageId, recipient, [count])
   SELECT
     messageId,
     recipient,
     [count]
   FROM CTE c
     WHERE providerId = @GSM_PROVIDER 
       AND rowNumber = 1   

   DECLARE @gmsMessagesFull table
   (
     messageId int,
     recipient varchar(20),
     lastStatusId int,
     [count] int
   )

   INSERT INTO @gmsMessagesFull(messageId, recipient, lastStatusId, [count])
   SELECT   
     g.messageId,
     g.recipient,
     (
       SELECT TOP 1 statusId
       FROM [dbo].[MessageStatus] ms
       WHERE ms.messageId = g.messageId
       ORDER BY messageStatusId DESC
     ) AS lastStatusId,
     g.[count]
   FROM @gmsMessages g

   SELECT 
     COUNT(*),
     SUM([dbo].func_GetGmsSmsCost (g.[recipient], g.[count]))
   FROM @gmsMessagesFull g
   WHERE g.lastStatusId IN (2, 6, 7, 9, 11)
   ```

**Лично я** считаю, что результат в обоих случаях должен быть одинаковым. ведь по сути мы запускаем один и тот же механизм.

UPD:
Результаты

exec SP
852458  | 193089.6790
t-sql:
880444  | 199485.5420

Comment: Если у вас есть "дубли" с неопределённостью (особенно внути `order by`), то результат часто разный - с эти сталкивался. Один раз выбирает одно за главное, второй раз другое. А всётаки покажите резальтаты 1 и 2 если не сложно...

Comment: Простите, "дубли" с неопределённостью, это как?

Comment: Результаты добавлены в вопрос. Кол-во сообщений/Стоимость

Comment: в хранимке входные даты - точно `datetime`  а не `date` ?

Comment: _"дубли" с неопределённостью, это как?_ Это когда Вы пишете ORDER BY field, а у Вас 2 записи с одинаковым значением field. В одной выборке Вы можете получить более раннюю запись, а потом более позднюю, а в другой наоборот. _Результаты добавлены в вопрос_ А Вы не пробовали сравнить те самые табличные переменные, которые получаете в процессе выполнения?

Comment: Да, проблема в том что у хранимки тип параметров DATE(!!!!)

Comment: @LeonardBertone ;)

Comment: Ну так ответ почему никто не напишет? Черкнуть несколько строк, пояснить ответ, получить плюс в репутацию.